# regex '\s+-\s*|\s*-\s+' does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

i am parsing a large list with a node.js application and have this code

```
sizeCode = dbfr.CN_DESC.split('\s+-\s*|\s*-\s+')
```

this does not seem to work as it returns

```
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT - MELANGE GREY - S' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT - MELANGE GREY - M' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT - MELANGE GREY - L' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT - WHITE - S' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT - WHITE - M' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT -WHITE - L' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC LOW CUT RACER BACK TUNIC VEST -WHITE - M' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC LOW CUT RACER BACK TUNIC VEST - WHITE -L' ]
```

where as if i just use

```
sizeCode = dbfr.CN_DESC.split(' - ')
```

works correctly, the issue i have though is that in some instances, i may have different position for the '-' dash character so for example:

```
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT -WHITE - L' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC LOW CUT RACER BACK TUNIC VEST -WHITE - M' ]
[ 'WOMEN\'S CC LOW CUT RACER BACK TUNIC VEST - WHITE -L' ]
```

but i don't want to split the T-SHIRT for example.

any advice much appreciated

Comment: [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lP9rF4/1) `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use regex delimiter in your regex:

```
sizeCode = dbfr.CN_DESC.split(/\s+-\s*|\s*-\s+/g)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bP6lC1/1)